# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useState) is not a function

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit, react-native-web

I setting up react-native-web app with redux-toolkit and have an error: Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useState) is not a function at rtk-query-react.esm.js

I created an issue with all screenshots here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2666

I will be glad to have any ideas on how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

Importing is different in react.

```
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query' // don't use this

/* React-specific entry point that automatically generates
   hooks corresponding to the defined endpoints */
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react' // use this one
```

You can check this answer in github from [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1420)

Comment: Yes, I saw this post, but I don't use this import anywhere. I use correct one: "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react" but webpack transpiles my import to "@reduxjs/toolkit/query", how you can see on third screenshot. can I somehow affect on this?

Comment: can you take a look on this article https://bionicjulia.com/blog/implementing-rtk-query-in-react-native-app

Comment: Yes, I saw this article, but i don't use the redux-persist. I have example repo for reproducing error: https://github.com/Babeev/react-native

Comment: I clone the project and start/ build the web but this issue didn't reproduce, can you specify how to reproduce it exactly!

Comment: Yes, please open src/pages/Auth/controller.ts and uncomment line 12 or line 13. After this you will see the error